# Couldn't start project on Android: could not connect to TCP port 5584: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:5584

Tags: android, reactjs, native

I am using EXPO React Native , when i want to run with USB debug (USB enabled ) , giving error:
Couldn't start project on Android: could not connect to TCP port 5584: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:5584[image]

how to fix this problem????